# Сделать текст с заглавной буквы

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как сделать текст с заглавной буквы? Есть текст на сайте, но он по умолчанию капс лок, надо как-то сделать его capitalize. Капеиталайз работает, когда текст изначально мелкий, а как сделать то же самое, когда он уже большой (то, что он большой нельзя изменить)

```css
p{
 text-transform:capitalize!IMPORTANT;   
}
```

```html
<p>
LOREM IPSUM
</p>
```

Comment: Так текст уже с заглавной буквы. Куда еще заглавнее?!

Comment: Да не, там надо в виде Привет Привет Привет,а не ПРИВЕТ ПРИВЕТ ПРИВЕТ.просто изначальные данные в каком то файле

Comment: Судя по ответам к [к этому вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322314/convert-uppercase-letter-to-lowercase-and-first-uppercase-in-sentence-using-css), средствами CSS так сделать не получится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно непосредственно "с заглавной буквы", то можно воспользоваться псевдоэлементом `:first-letter`:

```css
p {
   text-transform: lowercase;
}

p:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p>ТЕКСТ БОЛЬШУЩИЙ, БОЛЬШОЙ ТЕКСТ.</p>
```

Comment: Нужно капитализировать первую букву каждого слова, а не просто первую букву текста.

Comment: Если так, что с помощью только css не обойтись. Правда вот, что каждую букву из вопроса совершенно не очевидно.

Answer (score 4):

**Можно так:**

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].substring(1);
  }
  return splitStr.join(' ');
}

document.querySelector("p").textContent = titleCase(document.querySelector("p").textContent);
```

```html
<p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET</p>
```

Comment: Спс ,помогло.то, что нужно